# AS3 > Replace double quotes characters with \"

Tags: string, actionscript-3

How to replace standard quotes (') with \" in a String?

This is obviously not working:

```
s = s.split("'").join (" \" ");
```

And this gives me an error (of course):

```
s = s.split("'").join (" \\" ");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok sorry, I just called a friend of mine and talked about it.

Here the solution in case someone needs it

```
s = s.split("'").join ("\\\"");
```

Comment: I would suggest reading this explanation of the difference between string literals and string values. http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/26/String-Literals-vs-String-Values This should help you understand why you needed to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any solutions using String.replace()?  I couldn't get it to do exactly what you specified but it may be a good starting point.  The global tag makes it replace all instances instead of just the first.

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /'/g; // The 'g' tags the pattern as global  
var str:String = "Test'String";
trace(str.replace(myPattern, "\""));  
// Will output: Test"String
```

Taken from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace()

To expand:

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /'/g;
var myPattern2:RegExp = /\"/;
var str:String = "Test'String";
trace(str.replace(myPattern, myPattern2));  
// Will output: Test/\"/String
```

This leaves you with a string you would need to only remove the "/" characters to achieve your desired result.  Your solution is much simpler though, this is just an alternative.

Comment: Sorry but I think this is not going to replace with \" but only with "

Comment: As I said, I couldn't get it to do exactly as you specified but I thought it was a good place to start if you were out of ideas.  The output comment shows it does indeed only replace with " when I tested it.